# Why am I not able to call a function?Prototypal Inheritance

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

The following code doesn't work why?What do I need to fix?

```
  function f(tag){
  this.obj=document.createElement(tag);


obj.f='blue';


}
f.prototype.k={};
f.prototype.k.f='fue';
//f.prototype.obj.f='blue';
function o(){
  f.call(this,'div');
  this.func=function(){
   alert(this.k.f); 
   alert(this.obj.f);
  };


}
o.prototype=Object.create(f.prototype);
var s=new o();
s.func();
```

Comment: In what way does it not work? What do you expect it to do that it doesn't? Do you get errors on the console?

Comment: no errors on the console

Answer (score 1):

From the javascript console: **ReferenceError: obj is not defined.**

In the `function f(tag){`:

`obj.f='blue';` doesn't exist: it is: `this.obj.f = 'blue';`